# NZEC Resolution (Java)

Tags: java

I've been trying to solve an elementary problem based on the Shunting Yard algorithm (see: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/)

I've been through almost all questions based on NZEC (Non Zero Exit Condition) resolution. I'm just starting out with Java, but I think I have handled all possible exceptions here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InfixToPostfix{

    public static String postfixString(String expression){

        Stack <Character> valueStack = new Stack <Character>();
        Stack <Character> operatorStack = new Stack <Character>();

        char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();
        char temp;
        for(char c : tokens){

            if(c == '('){
                continue;
            }

            if((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')){
                valueStack.push(c);
            }

            else if(c == '+' || c== '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^'){
                operatorStack.push(c);
            }

            else if(c == ')'){
                temp = operatorStack.pop();
                valueStack.push(temp);
            }

        }
        return valueStack.toString();
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)throws java.lang.Exception{

        String inputString = "";
        int n1;
        Scanner numberOfTestCases = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(numberOfTestCases.hasNextInt())
        {
            n1 = numberOfTestCases.nextInt();


            StringBuilder[] sbuf = new StringBuilder[n1];
            Scanner inputExpression = new Scanner(System.in);

            for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){

                sbuf[i] = new StringBuilder();

                if(inputExpression.hasNextLine()){

                    inputString = inputExpression.nextLine();

                    sbuf[i].append(postfixString(inputString).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "").replaceAll(", ", ""));
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
                System.out.println(sbuf[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should also mention that I need to bring the size of the program down to less than 50kB; I'm almost certain that this is the issue which causes the NZEC. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You forgot to state your problem or question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My apologies. Will do.

Comment: Try again. What happens? How does that differ from what you expect to happen?

Comment: The code works perfectly on my machine; I've tried debugging it using a couple of online compilers/IDEs (http://ideone.com/ and http://www.codechef.com/ide respectively) and Eclipse (I usually stick to the command line), but to no avail. As far I can see, there are no un-handled exceptions which might give rise to an NZEC condition. The online judge which I use states that I need to have the source size down to 50000 bytes (http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/), hence my assumption.